# Connect terminal IPython to existing notebook kernel

Tags: python, ipython

Running `ipython --existing` resulted in:

`[TerminalIPythonApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--existing'`

Is there any way to have a IPython notebook sharing kernel with a terminal IPython instance? I prefer working in terminal over QT console because I'd like to manage my workflow with tmux. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command is:

```
ipython console --existing
```

`ipython` starts a single-process session, without zmq or a Kernel. `ipython console` starts the two-process version with the kernel code used by the qtconsole and notebook.

Comment: `ipython cosole` is deprecated. Issuing this command gives a warning to use `jupyter console` instead.